# Query on XML parsing in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

But it gives me exception like "There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 2." on the line `reader.MoveToContent();`

Below is the sample code that i use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Pictures\\test.xml");
            string contents = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                if (reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
                    contents += "<" + reader.Name + ">\n";
                if (reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
                    contents += reader.Value + "\n";
            }
            Console.Write(contents);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

please help.

Comment: its the whole xml where values "newbgm" and "123456789" will get changed dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse an XML document, that, stand-alone, isn't valid XML. Therefore, you need to tell it that it is only a fragment.  This will prevent it from throwing an error about multiple root elements.

You can do this by replacing the line

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Pictures\\test.xml");
```

with:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
var reader = System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Create("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Pictures\\test.xml", settings);
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. But when i execute it throws me "'v' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 4, position 17."  The idea is to search for "migr" in the xml string, after finding "::" needs to be ommited. Then it will find "tft1"and so on

Comment: it works for me with the xml you provided in the question. Can you double check the contents of the xml file you are parsing?

Comment: why do you have a double quote followed by a singe quote?

Comment: Thanks Keith. My bad. i missed a "_" in the tag. But doesn't it display the values like "migr" , tft1, 123456789, etc in the console.,